# How to make dropdown width equal to splitbutton width?

Tags: extjs

[image]

I have a splibutton with a menu item. I want to make the width of the drop down equal to the split button width. Additionally I want to align the text in the center. How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of the menu will be based on the width of the content inside. So if the width of the button will always be the same, you could set the width of the menu to that same value or you can get the width of the button and set it to the menu before rendering it.

As for centering the text, you have two options. Either via CSS, add a custom CLS to your menu and add the following CSS:

```
.yourCustomCls .x-menu-item-link {
    text-align: center;
}
.yourCustomCls .x-menu-item-indent-no-separator {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Or add the config plain: true to your menu and a style centering the text as in my example.

Example:

```
Ext.create('Ext.button.Split', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        text: 'Commit Automatically',
        menu: new Ext.menu.Menu({
            plain: true,
            style: 'text-align: center;',
            items: [
                {text: 'Commit On Trigger', handler: function(){ alert("Item 1 clicked"); }}
            ],
            listeners: {
                beforerender: function () {
                    this.setWidth(this.up('button').getWidth());
                }
            }
        })
    });
```

Comment: Great!! Solved the width problem. but I am not able to align the dropdown text in the center.

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I misread your text and thought you wanted to align the text to the left. I've updated the question with two possible solutions for centering it.

Comment: Yes, Now it align to the center